# "this" value, when creating a Tic Tac Toe game using Factory Functions, Modules, Event Listeners, and IIFE's in Javascript

Tags: javascript, events, module, iife

I'm working on a Tic Tac Toe game, where players take turns to mark the board.

At this stage, I'm trying to get the board to alternate between players each time a square is clicked. So when Player 1 clicks the board, Player 1's symbol is displayed on the clicked square, and it's Player 2's turn to select a square.

This is my first time working with Immediately-Invoked Function Expressions(IIFE's) and Factory Function, and I'm having a hard time getting the modules to work well together.

The process and problem is this:

- A module generates a board with 9 "square" objects and adds an
  eventListener to each square object. The eventListener fires a function when clicked.
- That eventListener function should do two things: modify the innerHTML of the "square" object, and change the current player
- The eventListener function uses a "this" variable, which should be the "square" object. **This is where the problem is**. When console logging, I find the "this" variable is the Window object, even though the eventListener is called on the "square" object.
- The current result is the function fires, but innerHTML of the clicked "square" is not modified because the object is the Window instead of the "square" object.

I don't understand why this is not working correctly and am having a hard time understanding how to work with objects between modules.

I've reviewed on Modules, IIFE's and eventListeners, but can't seem to find a good example that combines all of these and helps me understand the root of the problem.

```js
//Gameboard array
var boardModule = (() => {

  //Select div for board
  let boardContainer = document.querySelector("#boardContainer")
  let boardArray = ["x", "o", "x", "o", "x", "o", "x", "o", "x"];

  //Module Player Selection

  const gameFunctions = (() => {

    // Onclick function for board

    let currentPlayer;

    // Selection module
    const getPlayer = () => {

      switch (currentPlayer) {
        case undefined:
          currentPlayer = 1;
        case 1:
          console.log(this);
          this.innerHTML = "PLAYER 1 SELECTION";
          return currentPlayer = 2;
        case 2:
          this.innerHTML = "PLAYER 2 SELECTION"
          return currentPlayer = 1;
      }


    };


    return {
      getPlayer
    };

  })();



  //Module: Built board with for each

  const boardGenerator = () => {

    boardArray.forEach(element => {
      let square = document.createElement("div")
      square.classList.add("squareStyle")
      square.innerHTML = element
      square.addEventListener("click", gameFunctions.getPlayer);

      //Append to board
      boardContainer.appendChild(square);

    });
  }

  //Module: Build players

  const Player = (name, mark) => {
    getname = () => name;
    getmark = () => mark;

    const welcome = person => {
      console.log(`Welcome to ${person.getname()}`)
    }

    return {
      getname,
      getmark,
      welcome
    }
  }

  player1 = Player("player1", "X");
  player2 = Player("player2", "0");

  //Module: Square Selector
  return {
    boardGenerator,
    gameFunctions
  };

})();


boardModule.boardGenerator();
```

```css
html,
body {
  height: 100%;
}

* {
  font-family: Graphik Regular;
}

.container {
  height: 100%;
  padding: 0;
  margin: 0;
  display: flex;
  align-items: center;
  justify-content: center;
}

#boardContainer {
  display: flex;
  flex-wrap: wrap;
  align-items: center;
  justify-content: center;
  position: absolute;
  margin: 0 auto;
  width: 300px;
  height: auto;
}

.squareStyle {
  display: flex;
  height: 100px;
  width: 100px;
  background-color: red;
  position: relative;
  align-items: center;
  justify-content: center;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<meta charset="UTF-8">
<html lang="en">
<head>
  <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="style.css">
  </stylesheet>
  <script type="text/javascript" src="http://livejs.com/live.js"></script>
</head>
<body>
  <div class="container">
    <div id="boardContainer">
    </div>
  </div>
  <script src="script.js"></script>
</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is happenning because you are using an arrow function. Arrow functions are always binded to the parent scope, in your case is the `window` object.

Look at this example from [MDN Arrow Function Docs](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Functions/Arrow_functions):

```js
'use strict';

var obj = { // does not create a new scope
  i: 10,
  b: () => console.log(this.i, this),
  c: function() {
    console.log(this.i, this);
  }
}

obj.b(); // prints undefined, Window {...} (or the global object)
obj.c(); // prints 10, Object {...}
```

Comment: Thanks for the answer. You spotted that quickly! I went deep into review because I couldn't understand what wasn't working. All works now. Thanks so much!